# How to configure NTLM security on Apache http server?

Tags: apache-2.2, web-server, ntlm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to configure NTLM security on Apache http server on windows?](https://serverfault.com/questions/117055/how-to-configure-ntlm-security-on-apache-http-server-on-windows)

How to configure NTLM security on Apache http server?

Answer (score 0):

There is [mod_ntlm](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/) and [mod_auth_sspi](http://mod-auth-sspi.sourceforge.net/). You could try either of that.