# How to configure NTLM security on Apache http server on windows?

Tags: windows, apache-2.2, ntlm

How to configure NTLM security on Apache http server on windows?

Abdul khaliq

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [mod_ntlm](http://modntlm.sourceforge.net/) and [mod_auth_sspi](http://mod-auth-sspi.sourceforge.net/). You could try either of that.

PS: Your old question in stackoverflow was not deleted. its migrated [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/117048/how-to-configure-ntlm-security-on-apache-http-server).